# Writing extension for Drawing.Rectangle

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

Drawing.Rectangle has the method

```
Dim r As Drawing.Rectangle = Drawing.Rectangle.FromLTRB(...)
```

I would like to write an extension method similar to that function. The extension method would create a rectangle that would contain all given points.

I have written such a method, but "Rectangle" doesn't notice that it has this new method.

When I try to access the method, Intellisense won't find it.

I have declared the extension in a module like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function FromPoints(ByVal points As List(Of Drawing.Point)) As Drawing.Rectangle

    Dim leastX As Integer = 0
    Dim maxX As Integer = 0
    Dim leastY As Integer = 0
    Dim maxY As Integer = 0

    Dim bDone As Boolean = False

    For Each p As Point In points
        If Not bDone Then
            bDone = True
            leastX = p.X
            maxX = p.X
            leastY = p.Y
            maxY = p.Y
        Else
            If p.X < leastX Then
                leastX = p.X
            End If
            If p.X > maxX Then
                maxX = p.X
            End If
            If p.Y < leastY Then
                leastY = p.Y
            End If
            If p.Y > maxY Then
                maxY = p.Y
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return Drawing.Rectangle.FromLTRB(leastX, leastY, maxX, maxY)

End Function
```

Did I miss anything to make it work?

Comment: What an extension method extends is not identified by what it returns, but rather by its first argument. So if the first argument is a `List(Of Point)` then the extension method will be added for an object of type `List(Of Point)`. Note that extension methods cannot be `Shared`, they only work on instantiated objects.

Comment: For more information refer to the documentation: [Extension Methods (Visual Basic) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FromLTRB` method you cite is `Shared`, i.e. it is a member of the `Rectangle` type but not of a `Rectangle` instance.  Notice that you call it on `Rectangle` but not on A `Rectangle`.

Extension methods can only be used as though they are instance members.  You can't write an extension method that you call on the `Rectangle` type but only that you call on a `Rectangle` instance.  The instance that you call it on is actually represented by the first parameter.  Your extension method would have to look like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module RectangleExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function FromPoints(source As Rectangle, points As List(Of Point)) As Rectangle
        '...
    End Function

End Module
```

and then you would have to call it like this:

```
Dim rect As Rectangle
Dim points As New List(Of Point)

'...

Dim newRect = rect.FromPoints(points)
```

That's not exactly ideal because you have to have a `Rectangle` to begin with but there's no way around that because an extension method requires an instance of the type being extended to be called on.

By the way, I would tend to write that method like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module RectangleExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function FromPoints(source As Rectangle, points As IEnumerable(Of Point)) As Rectangle
        Dim pointArray = points.ToArray()
        Dim allX = pointArray.Select(Function(p) p.X).ToArray()
        Dim allY = pointArray.Select(Function(p) p.Y).ToArray()

        Return Rectangle.FromLTRB(allX.Min(),
                                  allY.Min(),
                                  allX.Max(),
                                  allY.Max())
    End Function

End Module
```

Using `IEnumerable(Of Point)` makes the method more flexible and using LINQ makes it more succinct.  The LINQ actually makes the performance worse but you'd have to have a significantly large list of `Points` for it to make any noticeable difference.

EDIT:

I should point out explicitly that the fact that an extension method requires an instance and this scenario doesn't require an instance prior to calling the method means that you shouldn't be using an extension method in this case.  Just write a method that takes a list of `Points` and returns a `Rectangle` and put it somewhere appropriate:

```
Public Function RectangleFromPoints(points As IEnumerable(Of Point)) As Rectangle
    Dim pointArray = points.ToArray()
    Dim allX = pointArray.Select(Function(p) p.X).ToArray()
    Dim allY = pointArray.Select(Function(p) p.Y).ToArray()

    Return Rectangle.FromLTRB(allX.Min(),
                              allY.Min(),
                              allX.Max(),
                              allY.Max())
End Function
```